# Get added/removed/changed key=>value pairs between two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two multidimensional arrays called $old and $new.  I want to compare the two arrays and see what k=>v's were added, removed, or changed between the two.

These are the arrays:

```
$old = array(
    'ONE'   => array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3),
    'TWO'   => array('a' => 4, 'b' => 5, 'c' => 6),
    'THREE' => array('a' => 7, 'b' => 8, 'c' => 9)
);

$new = array(
    'TWO'   => array('a' => 5, 'b' => 5, 'c' => 6),
    'THREE' => array('a' => 7, 'b' => 8, 'c' => 9),
    'FOUR'  => array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3)
);
```

Notice that in the $new array I have removed 'ONE', added 'FOUR', and changed the value of 'TWO'=>'a' from 4 to 5.

This is my current (working) solution, but I feel that I don't need to write this much code and I'm unsure if it will be slow on much larger arrays.

```
$added = array();
$removed = array();
$changed = array();

foreach ($old as $old_key => $old_value) {
    if (!in_array($old_key, array_keys($new))) {
        $removed[] = $old_value;
        unset($old[$old_key]);
    }
}

foreach ($new as $new_key => $new_value) {
    if (!in_array($new_key, array_keys($old))) {
        $added[] = $new_value;
        unset($new[$new_key]);
    }
}

$changed = array_udiff($new, $old, create_function(
    '$a,$b',
    'return strcmp(implode("", $a), implode("", $b));'
));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_diff_key`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) to easily find out which items have been added or removed:

```
$removed = array_diff_key($old, $new);
$added = array_diff_key($new, $old);
```

To find out which items have changed you can first use [`array_intersect_key`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) to narrow down on the possible candidates and straight array comparison to see what has changed:

```
$possiblyChanged = array_intersect_key($old, $new);
foreach ($possiblyChanged as $key => $value) {
    if ($new[$key] !== $value) {
         $changed[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a way using more of the built in functions. Thanks for the quick and complete response.